Nordic Sampo S2 RFID Scanner
I have a RFID scanner Nordic Sampo S2.
I have been trying to get some diagnostic data out of it using C++ but the function always ends up returning 1 which means error:
ret = NurApiDiagGetReport(hApi, flags, &report, sizeof(report));
SDK: https://github.com/NordicID/nur_sdk/tree/master/native
My main.cpp
#include "NurAPI.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void ShowErrorAndExitIfNeeded(HANDLE hApi, int error)
{
    if (error != NUR_NO_ERROR && error != NUR_ERROR_NO_TAG)
    {
        TCHAR errorMsg[128+1];
        NurApiGetErrorMessage(error, errorMsg, 128);
        _tprintf(_T("\r\nNurApi error %d: [%s]\r\n"), error, errorMsg);
        // Free API object
        NurApiFree(hApi);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

int main() {
    HANDLE hApi;
    int ret = 0;
    struct NUR_DIAG_REPORT report;
    memset(&report, 0, sizeof(report));
    DWORD flags = 0;default is intended

    // Initialize the API
    hApi = NurApiCreate();
    if (hApi == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to create NUR API handle.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("API handle created successfully.\n");

    // Attempt to open a connection to the NUR device
    ret = NurApiSetUsbAutoConnect(hApi, 1);
    if (ret != NUR_NO_ERROR) {
        ShowErrorAndExitIfNeeded(hApi, ret);
    }

    printf("Attempting to connect to NUR device...\n");
    printf("Connected to NUR device successfully.\n");

    // Prepare to get the diagnostic report
    ret = NurApiDiagGetReport(hApi, flags, &report, sizeof(report));
    if (ret == NUR_NO_ERROR) {
        printf("Diagnostic report obtained successfully.\n");
        printf("Temperature: %d C\n", report.temperature);
        printf("Battery voltage: %d mV\n", report.uptime);
    } else {
        ShowErrorAndExitIfNeeded(hApi, ret);
    }

    // Close the connection and free API
    NurApiFree(hApi);

    return 0;
}


Output
API handle created successfully.
Attempting to connect to NUR device...
Connected to NUR device successfully.

NurApi error 1: [I]


Platform: Windows 11 Pro x64 (Using the DLL and lib for the same architecture)
If someone likes to try it here is my CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26)
project(nordic)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

# Gather all source (.cpp) and header (.h) files in the current directory
file(GLOB_RECURSE PROJECT_SOURCES "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cpp" "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/*.h")
list(FILTER PROJECT_SOURCES EXCLUDE REGEX "CMakeCXXCompilerId\\.cpp$")

# Add an executable based on the gathered source files
add_executable(nordic ${PROJECT_SOURCES})

include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

link_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})

find_library(NURAPI_LIBRARY NAMES NURAPI PATHS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
if(NOT NURAPI_LIBRARY)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "NURAPI.lib not found in ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}")
endif()

target_link_libraries(nordic ${NURAPI_LIBRARY})

Files that I have in my CLion project
$ ls
CMakeLists.txt  NurAPI.h           NurAPIErrors.h  NurAccessoryExtension.h  NurOs_Linux.h  NurOs_iOS.h    SensorExample.cpp  SetupExample.cpp  cmake-build-debug    cmake-build-minsizerel  cmake-build-relwithdebinfo
NURAPI.lib      NurAPIConstants.h  NurAPIExport.h  NurOS.h                  NurOs_Win32.h  NurOs_macOS.h  SensorExample.h    SetupExample.h    cmake-build-default  cmake-build-release     main.cpp


Thanks
